# Meteor.js leaderboard example, how to change button value reactively?

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming, leaderboard

I tried to play with the leaderboard example by adding a button to toggle sorting by name/score.

I succeed in adding event, but I also want to change the text value on the button.

I expect the added button text value(sort by **name/score**) get updated reactively(every time I click the button), however it fails to do so, only get updated when manually click on the player item.

Code added:

leaderboard.html(leaderboard template):

```
    <template name="leaderboard">
    <div class="leaderboard">
    <input type="button" name="sort" value="Sort by {{sort_type}}" class='sort'/>

     {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
     {{/each}}
    </div>

    {{#if selected_name}}
      <div class="details">
        <div class="name">{{selected_name}}</div>
        <input type="button" class="inc" value="Give 5 points" />
       </div>
    {{else}}
      <div class="none">Click a player to select</div>
    {{/if}}
   </template>
```

leaderboard.js(client part):

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.startup(function(){
        Session.setDefault('sort_order', {score: -1, name: 1});
    Session.setDefault('sort', 'name');
    }); 

    Template.leaderboard.players = function () {
      return Players.find({}, {sort: Session.get('sort_order')});
    };

    Template.leaderboard.selected_name = function () {
      var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
      return player && player.name;
    };

    Template.leaderboard.sort_type = function() {
  return Session.get('sort');
    };

    Template.player.selected = function () {
      return Session.equals("selected_player", this._id) ? "selected" : '';
    };

    Template.leaderboard.events({
      'click input.inc': function () {
        Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});
      },

      'click input.sort': function(){
        var sort_order = Session.get('sort_order');
    if (_.isEqual(sort_order, {score: -1, name: 1}) || _.isEqual(sort_order, {score: 1})) {
        Session.set('sort_order', {name: 1});
            Session.set('sort', 'score');
    } else if (_.isEqual(sort_order, {name: 1})){
        Session.set('sort_order', {score: 1});
        Session.set('sort', 'name');
    }  

  }
    });
      Template.player.events({
        'click': function () {
           Session.set("selected_player", this._id);
        } 
    });
   }
```

Thanks!

B.R.

Ian

Comment: Can you post your HTML template, your helper function, and your event handler for the button? Your JavaScript functions seem fine but it's really difficult to tell because the code is all minified on deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the `preserve-inputs` package. From the Meteor Docs:

> By default, new Meteor apps automatically include the preserve-inputs package. This preserves all elements of type input, textarea, button, select, and option that have unique id attributes or that have name attributes that are unique within an enclosing element with an id attribute. To turn off this default behavior, simply remove the preserve-inputs package.

So basically because your button has a `name` attribute, Meteor is preventing it from changing when the template is re-rendered. There are three ways you can solve this:

1. Simply remove the `name` attribute from your `input.sort` attribute.
2. Remove the `preserve-inputs` package (not recommended if you're using the current template engine).
3. You can use the preview release of the new Meteor template engine, which no longer needs the `preserve-inputs` package because it automatically does more fine-grained DOM updates. You can run the app once with the preview release using:

   ```
   meteor --release shark-1-29-2014-e
   ```

   Or you can tell Meteor to update your app to this version by running:

   ```
   meteor update --release shark-1-29-2014-e
   ```

   Note that this new templating engine will be included in the Meteor core release by 1.0.

Comment: on v0.8 now with blaze, seems not working again though blaze claims it should update DOM with finer granularity?